# Unable to fork DevOps git repo - service not supported

Tags: git, fork, devops

I am trying to fork a DevOps git repo and I repeatedly get this error:

> TF400860: The current version of the following service is not supported: GitOdb. Version: 1700, MinVersion: 1700.

[image: Fork Error]

This exact operation worked for me last week.  Any ideas why it isn't working now?

Comment: It's a current (and I hope temporary) [issue](https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/188823884)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is some service degradation. It's probably just a matter of time until it starts working again. You can follow this [problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1041389/git-repos-in-azure-devops-are-empty.html) in the Developer Community. There is also the [status page for azure devops](https://status.dev.azure.com/).

Answer (score 2):

There is a service disruption on Microsoft side on **Repos** and **Pipelines** in the United States.  Microsoft seems to be on top of it, and as of writing this comment, it's been 29 minutes.  They'll fix it sometime soon, so we just have to sit and wait.

Duarte Silva provided some good links for the status page for Azure DevOps

Answer (score 1):

Here is the comment from Azure Dev Ops.

The issue is now fully mitigated with the completed rollback. This was caused by a unique intersection of updates over the past two days that didn't follow our normal compatibility constraints. We will be addressing that before the next deployment and have a repair item to identify solutions to prevent future occurrences of this. We apologize for the impact this had on our customers.

For More: https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/188823884